# Update RecyclerView when something happens in the Holder

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

So, here's my project structure. It's just a two tab app.

On the left tab, there's a list of all the available items. On the right tab, there's a list of the user favorite items. In each item there's a button where you click and then that item becomes a favorite. Well, at least that's what I want to achieve. Apparently the items get added to the favorites list, but at the moment the only way to see the new favorites list is closing and reopening the app.

What I need is some way to call the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when the item is added as favorite.

Right now, this favorite functionality is done as a method from the Holder I'm using. So, basically the user clicks the fav button on the item, and then the Holder has a `clickListener` which updates an Array that I store as a **JSON** in the `SharedPreferences`, which contains all the favorites items.

Those two tabs are Fragments, and each Fragment has a `RecyclerView`. They both use the same class:

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    private PageViewModel pageViewModel;

    private int section;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private SharedPreferences prefs = null;

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int index) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, index);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PageViewModel.class);
        int index = 1;
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            index = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        }

        section = index;
        pageViewModel.setIndex(index);
        prefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences("app_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.items_list);

        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        List<ItemModel> itemList= new ArrayList<>();

        // All Items Tab
        if (section == 1) {
            // Here I get all the Items and set them in the itemList Array

        else { // Favorite Items Tab (it retrieves an array of items stored in the SharedPreferences)
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = prefs.getString("favoriteList", "");

            if (json.isEmpty()) {

            } else {
                Type type = new TypeToken<List<ItemModel>>() {
                }.getType();

                itemList= gson.fromJson(json, type);
            }
        }

        MyItemAdapter itemAdapter = new MyItemAdapter (getContext(), getActivity(), itemList, section);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged()` is a not a solution, well it is but only if all else fail. Read about `DiffUtils` and implement interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `MutableLiveData` to observe your list, you can then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the observe block.
So, for example,

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private MutableLiveData<List<ItemModel>> mMutableLiveData;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mMutableLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
               rootView.findViewById(R.id.items_list).getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        List<ItemModel> itemList= new ArrayList<>();

        // All Items Tab
        if (section == 1) {
            // Here I get all the Items and set them in the itemList Array

        else { // Favorite Items Tab (it retrieves an array of items stored in the SharedPreferences)
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = prefs.getString("favoriteList", "");

            if (json.isEmpty()) {

            } else {
                Type type = new TypeToken<List<ItemModel>>() {
                }.getType();

                itemList= gson.fromJson(json, type);
                mMutableLiveData.setValue(itemList);
            }
        }

        MyItemAdapter itemAdapter = new MyItemAdapter (getContext(), getActivity(), itemList, section);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: @guillefix Check and see if my updated answer sample works.

Comment: I forgot that `Fragment` doesn't provide the `findViewById()` method like `Activity` or `View`. Just use your inflated view instead.

Comment: The "rootView" inside the onChanged gets marked in red and says "Variable 'rootView' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared". If I declare rootView as final, then it says that "Cannot resolve method 'getAdapter'"

Comment: Did you try typecasting the view to `RecyclerView`?

Comment: There's a bunch of safety checks I've missed since this was supposed to just be a simple example to give you a basic idea. For eg, you shouldn't directly call `notifyDataSetChanged` from the `getAdapter`, you might get a NPE.

Comment: Sorry, but what's a NPE?

Comment: @guillefix Null Pointer Exception.

Answer (score 0):

As you're already using SharedPreferences to save your favorites list, you can register a listener on it to get updates whenever it gets updated and then you can retrieve those changes from `SharedPreferences` and then update your list.

In your Fragment's `onCreateView()` method where you check this condition:

```
// All Items Tab
    if (section == 1) {
        // Here I get all the Items and set them in the itemList Array

    else { // Favorite Items Tab (it retrieves an array of items stored in the SharedPreferences)

        pref.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key){
                // here you can retrieve updated data from SharedPreferences and update your list
            }
        });

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = prefs.getString("favoriteList", "");

        if (json.isEmpty()) {

        } else {
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<ItemModel>>() {
            }.getType();

            itemList= gson.fromJson(json, type);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I don't know what do I have to pass as an argument for the method registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't seem to work, as I have to declare my adapter as final if I want to use it inside the onSharedPreferenceChanged

Comment: @guillefix then declare it final man! It won't create any issues. You need to create adapter only once.